# Ajax requesting incorrect url ( Rails project )

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to delete an entry in my database by requesting an URL via Ajax, my JavaScript code is the following:

```
function disableService(id) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'DELETE',
    url: '/app/delete_service/',
    data: { id: id },
    success: function() {
      // SOME CODE HERE //
    }
  });
}
```

In my `routes` file I have the following route to handle the request:

```
delete 'delete_service', to: 'company_services#destroy'
```

But when I try to make the request it seems like Ajax overrides the URL and request another URL even if I copy/paste the code itself in the inspector's console.

As you can see in the screenshot the URL in the code is totally different from the requested URL.

[image: Screenshot]

NOTE: It doesn't work with methods POST or DELETE but it works with GET. I know I can use GET method but it is not the correct way.

---------- UPDATE -------------

I already tried Rails canonical way:

Routes.rb:

```
resources :company_services
```

And this is the result, it overrides the original URL `app/company_services/:id` for `app/company_services` without `:id`

[image]

And these are my routes (related with `:company_services`)

[image]

Comment: I don't think you need `app` in your URL. Also, I wonder why you don't just use `resource :company_services` in your `routes.rb` and use `DELETE /company_services/:id`. It *might* help is you add to your question your console output.

Comment: Yes I did it that way at first but it doesn't work, the URL was `/app/company_services/:id` but it was the same thing, it requested `/app/company_services/` without the `:id`. And `app` is the namespace since I have two namespaces, one for the admin (`/admin`), one for the user (`/app`) and one for the website (`/`).

Comment: Show your controller code

Comment: Just to clarify, you have `//= require jquery` and `//= require jquery_ujs` in your application.js?

Comment: Change `type: 'DELETE'`, to `data: {'action': 'delete'},`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question hopefully can be useful for someone else with the same problem:

The problem was that the action of the controller in charge of handle the request has a redirect to `app_company_services_path`. I was trying to redirect to `company_services` after saving the changes but I was unfamiliar with how javascript requests behaves after a redirect.

My error:

```
def destroy
  # some code here
  redirect_to app_company_services_path
end
```

Correct way:

```
def destroy
  # some code here
  render json: { success: 'something here' }, status: 200
end
```

And then redirect with JS instead of trying to redirect directly from Rails.

Answer (score 0):

You try to the following like this

```
#=> routes.rb
resources :company_services
#=> DELETE /company_services/:id(.:format) # this is your link format
```

Now edit your `AJAX` code

```
function disableService(id) {
  var id = 45;
  $.ajax({
    type: 'DELETE',
    url: '/app/company_services/' + id,
    success: function(response) {
      // SOME CODE HERE //
    }
  });
}
```

Hope to help

Comment: Yes I did it that way at first but it doesn't work, the URL was `/app/company_services/:id` but it was the same thing, it requested `/app/company_services/` without the :id.

Comment: What you pass `id` properly

Comment: It's showing not passing `id` to the URL, you make sure that

Comment: You can test this `url: '/app/company_services/45'` make sure `id` already exist

Comment: I did but unfortunately I get the same error after setting `url: '/app/company_services/45` this way.

Comment: what is the `app` in your URL directory try without `app`, i have updated answer for URL rewrite @danielavila

Comment: `app` is the namespace but it is defined in my `routes.rb` file, I updated the question, you can see the routes related with `:company_services` in the image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162388/discussion-between-fool-and-danielavila).

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this

 `id = '45'
 url: '/app/company_services/' + id
 Or please try direct URL: 'app/company_services/45' just to test once.`

Hope can help.